# Need to extract a value on the url

Tags: jmeter

I am getting JSON response as

```
"imageUrl": "https:\/\/s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com\/aws-channel-dss-r1-apsouth1-system\/abc\/Turf%20Banner2_2022-10-10_065755319_2022-10-10_065756.969.JPEG?X-Amz-Security-Token...."
```

In which i want to extract only `Turf%20Banner2_2022-10-10_065755319_2022-10-10_065756.969.JPEG?'
I have tried with JSON extractor

```
$..imageUrl
```

Match random : 0
Next with `Regular Expression Extractor` with (.+?)
[Check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzZ9g.png)

Any suggestions pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to use the following regular expression:

```
/abc/(.+?)\?
```

where:

- `()` - grouping
- `.` - any character
- `+` - repetition
- `?` - non-greedy match
- `\` - escape `?` which is a [meta-character](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars)

If you have problems coming up with a proper regular expression you could use [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor) instead, in this case you only need to provide "left" and "right" boundaries and it will fetch everything in-between

[image]